# If $\lim_{z \to z_o} f(z)=w_o$ and $ \lim_{w \to w_o} g(w)=L$ then $ \lim_{z \to z_o} g(f(z))=L$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, proof-writing

If $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_o} f(z)=w_o$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{w \to w_o} g(w)=L$ then  $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_o} g(f(z))=L$.

$f$ and $g$ are complex functions with $R_f \subset D_g$.

$z_o$ and $w_o$ are accumulation points.

I wrote the definitions for both limits . But how could I get $\lim_{z \to z_o} g(f(z))=L$ using them ?

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that

$$|g(w)-L|<\epsilon$$

whenever $0<|w-w_0|<\delta$.

For that corresponding $\delta>0$ (this is a "new" $\epsilon$ for the second limit), there exists a $\nu>0$ (this is the "new" $\delta$ for the second limit) such that

$$|f(z)-w_0|<\delta$$

whenever $0<|z-z_0|<\nu$.

Therefore, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\nu>0$ such that $|g(f(z))-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\nu$.